# How to constructor a class with one generic type and other base types v typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem how to create a constructor for a class if I have multiple types and one of them is generic.

```
export interface IResultModel<T> {

    EventType : string;
    Process : string;
    Service : string;
    Alert : string;
    IsSuccess : boolean;
    Message : string;
    Data : T;
}

export class ResultModel<T> implements IResultModel<T> {

    EventType : string = '';
    Process : string = '';
    Service : string = '';
    Alert : string = '';
    IsSuccess : boolean = false;
    Message : string = '';
    Data : T  // how to initialize ;


    constructor(initializer?: IResultModel<T>) {
        if (!initializer) return;
        
        if (initializer.EventType) this.EventType = initializer.EventType;
        if (initializer.Process) this.Process = initializer.Process;
        if (initializer.Service) this.Service = initializer.Service;
        if (initializer.Alert) this.Alert = initializer.Alert;
        if (initializer.IsSuccess) this.IsSuccess = initializer.IsSuccess;
        if (initializer.Message) this.Message = initializer.Message;
        if (initializer.Data) this.Data = initializer.Data; // how to instantiate a generic type
    }
}
```

It is not clear to me how to initialize a generic data type and create an instance of the generic type in the constructor.

Comment: If `Data` could remain uninitialized you should declate it as `Data?: T` or `Data : T | undefined` (and your code suggests it can, since some code paths from the constructor do not  initialize it).

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Changed the approach based on Grochni's comments.

You can use a [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization) on Data and then initialize it in the constructor with whatever type you need.

```js
Data!: T // Now you don't need to initialize it with a value.
```

Now, type of `T` can be inferred from what you assign to `this.Data`.

```js
const resultModelInstance = new ResultModel({ Data: { someType: "somedata" }, ... })
// Type of "resultModelInstance": ResultModel<{ someType: string; }>
const data = resultModelInstance.Data
// type of "data": { someType: string; }
```

or you can decide what type Data should be

```js
const resultModelInstance = new ResultModel<number>({ Data: 0 }, ... })
// Anything different than "number" on Data will produce an error
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcCuAbMAWQHsATCPAHgBUA+ZAbwCgnk3kBRANwnGoE8ADigBcyLGCigA5gG5W7AApRiSLFmRiJUkHIVsAytC7Akm8ZJnz2yAIJ5oYc9qv60WAzgRqNYgEbExA5wINbshNhYcNKiFjp6NgAicGBw5tTyAL4sCHhw6siYuAQk5FR0yMAAtoIOVbxgGhjY+ERkFDT0zG7cDQLCzpa6yAC8yADk42FsyqqRg-GjE1NuRlAmZlpD0kuT03YOUE5bi2N7bqgeXj7mAUEQIUvweFgQ+xHq0bEuw2crSSk4ABCMQZFhuBDEEDaLxgYhQAAUoGAYGAcDwwAAXtAAPxiZrFNplToASkYbhswBgyARQORqPRWOgZKgEDAOCgoQp7G5bCpNPpaIx2KgADpenwhBAyWAABbALDiniSgZjQWMkVKvpS-aU6lIkAooVMsWzHwy+WKs3zNWGhnC6Ci63qXXsfkGo0ax1rDbS5ByhWin2mFC2z0OsXBpCuvn69UR0X2RwWwNJo5LeMmxOHMAxypxu3GzWXTzeSIpxUl642yqFr1iqtll28-MCusJj5RGIV0Wdr4Z9tZvsxPPuzOa5KpHuTtJh+1ZmeyZAAemXyFlxAA7v7iLWJCEGZBkGkYiBoKZ-VK3NlskxIdCnKzCaUKKgHyEzGMz9uiq0X3gEQYZAZzEICsGIep+ggMQACJwPqUhARg5BMgAGk4ZUwCg2C-Bg9DnSwWCEDw5Ao2g5AYNIEi0zAWCIBIxsfDESQcAgdDh3ImD6k+GJkMyEk7yhCRkEQ1IlifP92jwN99xAJBRRnJhlwAKjYKDkGIalRLgUDxAgiBsLiKwULcdTNOQCSSikmTUjk8jfys4kwP0wyfjkFDaCYZTlxYVdkAAeSgZB+GIHBkAQR58iwYBpBAZBN1lFIIB4S8BhMNI5RQU9zwQZBBIfCyWkc193zsgA5HAqj8aAlm-QoiqJDoQEq6qoFoQDgMBMQAAZ0IlLCpRwkiCKIkiyNgqj0JouiGKuJtCP9KBWPYyIvlg7iu3olCBPvYTLMa6TSqQCqqugDgoBUIKvwgH8Gv-ShmtOtqOpAiiQn4ANhmITKgrlR5Hta+LgDwPBkEEFRSC8FBoEurASP6wyYNw-CVCYijiPQ8aKMmg5HBm9DGMiZilrY5AOPW1beO2pS13Oy7kAAWiZ5mWdZtn2Y5zmudoAA-PmeaAA)

Comment: This is unsafe, as `undefined` might not be assignable to `T`, so you basically destroy type safety with this solution. If you want to be able to assign undefined to the field, just change its type to `T | undefined`.

Comment: `undefined` has been used as an example to show how type assertion works because the author didn't provide any info on what shape `T` would be

Comment: There is no info about what shape T will be, it's a generic. It could be `number` or `string` or an object type, you don't know how it's going to be used, that's the point of generics. And what you do in your code is not a type assertion, it's a cast - an unsafe one, because you are casting a value to a type that it's not neccessarily assignable to.

Comment: Sorry, I need to correct myself after looking it up: what you do IS a type assertion. Sorry for the confusion. However, it still is unsafe and if `T` is a generic without constraint there's no type assertion that would be safe.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed the approach based on your suggestion because it was truly type unsafe. Now it should look good.

Comment: This is unsafe as well, it tells the compiler that Data will necessarily be initialized which is not true from the implementation of the constructor.

Comment: More precisely: The use case you are missing is calling the constructor without argument. In that case Data is not initialized and any code depending on it being initialized will error.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, that for a generic without any constraints, there's no value that's guaranteed to be assignable to the field. So you can either change the type of the field or provide a possibility to get an instance of `T`,

If you change the field's type, for example to `T | undefined` instead of `T`, undefined will also be assignable, so you can initialize it with this value.

Another option is to pass a default instance or a function that returns a default instance to your constructor. If you change your constructor like this:

```
constructor(getDefaultT: () => T, initializer?: IResultModel<T>) {
  if (!initializer) return;
  
  // ...

  this.Data = initializer.Data ?? getDefaultT();
}
```

Then your code will compile and you can use it like this:

```
const numberResultModel = new ResultModel<number>(() => -1);
const stringResultModel = new ResultModel<string>(() => '');
const objectResultModel = new ResultModel<SomeClass>(() => new SomeClass());
```

Comment: Using `T | undefined` or changing the constructor is not needed. A definite assignment assertion like `Data!: T` can be used to avoid initialization and leave it to the constructor, where type can be inferred or passed via a type argument as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442658/17607331)

Comment: Using `T | undefined` is the better approach as it is more accurate. Using a definite assignment assertion just tricks the compiler, same as using a type assertion with incompatible types. My solutions provide real type safety, not just code that compiles.